# Namespace does not work for socket.io-client in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Namespace on web page client works fine for me:

```
// Browser side JS: processed by browserify
var io = require('socket.io-client')('/namespace');
io.emit("message", data);
```

Server receives connect and the message without any problem. However if I try to make client app with node.js name space does not work. Code is following:

## test.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {
    reconnect: true,
    path: '/namespace'
});

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('Test connected!');
});

socket.emit('message', data);
```

In this case running `node test.js` client never connects to the server and can't emit any message. On server side console I see following output:

`GET /namespace/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MT0IoBp&b64=1 404 22.327 ms - 1423`

Any ideas? Bug or need to setup namespace in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed node.js client code to

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/namespace', {
    reconnect: true
});
```

works fine!